# Scala- Conscript - "An unexpected error occurred: Please check your internet connection"

Tags: scala, scalatra, giter8, scalatra-sbt

**Context:** I'd like to install conscript and giter8 so that I can more efficiently create and work with Scalatra project files. I've followed the instructions [here](http://www.foundweekends.org/conscript/setup.html) and [here](https://github.com/foundweekends/conscript) to download and run the jar. When I do so I get the following error. I get the same error when running the Powershell script. While I am on a private network, my internet connection is fine. And when I follow the location in the exception message I hit a strange page which looks like a list of Github directories - not sure what to do with that.

```
"An unexpected error occurred: Please check your internet connection. 
Exception message: https://api.github.com/repos/foundweekends/conscript/git/refs/"
```

[image]

**Question:** Can someone please let me know what I'm doing wrong? And explain how I can get conscript up and running properly?

UPDATE: running the jar still is not working but I re-tried running the powershell script and that does look like it was able to successfully install conscript. When I cd into the **.conscript\bin directory** and run `cs foundweekends/giter8` I'm still getting this strange error which indicates to me either conscript or giter8 is still not up and running correctly.

```
c:\Users\e.b\.conscript\bin>cs foundweekends/giter8
An unexpected error occurred: Please check your internet connection.
Exception message: 
https://api.github.com/repos/foundweekends/giter8/git/refs/heads/master

c:\Users\e.b\.conscript\bin>
```

When I navigate to the URL provided I then get a message that reads.

> {   "message": "Not Found",   "documentation_url":
> "https://docs.github.com/rest" }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found some additional documentation that seems to resolve the issue: http://www.foundweekends.org/giter8/

When I run cmd and execute `sbt new scala/scala-seed.g8` I'm able to successfully setup Scalatra templates.